# Error operating on file using grass

Tags: python, grass-gis

```
from grass.pygrass.modules.shortcuts import raster as r

gscript.run_command('g.region', raster='C:\\Users\\rit\\Documents\\PhD\\Projects\\Intensity\\input\\2008_cdls\\MI\\cdl_30m_r_mi_2008_albers.tif')
```

results in the foll. error:

```
*** CalledModuleError: Module run None ['g.region', 'raster=C:\\Users\\rit\\Documents\\PhD\\Projects\\Intensity\\input\\2008_cdls\\MI\\cdl_30m_r_mi_2008_albers.tif'] ended with error
ERROR: Raster map
Process ended with non-zero return code 1. See errors in the (error) output.
       <C:\Users\rit\Documents\PhD\Projects\Intensity\input\2008_cdls\MI\cdl_30m_r_mi_2008_albers.tif>
       not found
```

What could be going wrong? the file I am trying to run the command on does exist

-- EDIT: Based on Micha's response:

```
import grass.script as gscript
import grass.script.setup as gsetup
from grass.pygrass.modules.shortcuts import raster as r

gscript.run_command('r.in.gdal', input="C:\Users\rit\Documents\PhD\Projects\Intensity\input\2008_cdls\MI\\cdl_30m_r_mi_2008_albers.tif", flags='e',output='C:\Users\rit\Documents\PhD\Projects\Intensity\input\2008_cdls\MI\cdl_30m_r_mi_2008_albers')
gscript.run_command('g.region', raster='C:\\Users\\rit\\Documents\\PhD\\Projects\\Intensity\\input\\2008_cdls\\MI\\cdl_30m_r_mi_2008_albers.tif')
```

I still get this error:

```
ERROR: Unable to open datasource
it\Documents\PhD\Projects\Intensity\input�8_cdls\MI\cdl_30m_r_mi_2008_albers.tif>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rit/Documents/PhD/Projects/GLAM/Code/Code/Conditions/misc_codes.py", line 88, in <module>
    gscript.run_command('r.in.gdal', input="C:\Users\rit\Documents\PhD\Projects\Intensity\input\2008_cdls\MI\\cdl_30m_r_mi_2008_albers.tif", flags='e',output='C:\Users\rit\Documents\PhD\Projects\Intensity\input\2008_cdls\MI\cdl_30m_r_mi_2008_albers')
  File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 7.0.4\etc\python\grass\script\core.py", line 395, in run_command
    return handle_errors(returncode, returncode, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS 7.0.4\etc\python\grass\script\core.py", line 313, in handle_errors
    returncode=returncode)
grass.exceptions.CalledModuleError: Module run None ['r.in.gdal', '-e', 'input=C:\\Users\rit\\Documents\\PhD\\Projects\\Intensity\\input\x808_cdls\\MI\\cdl_30m_r_mi_2008_albers.tif', 'output=C:\\Users\rit\\Documents\\PhD\\Projects\\Intensity\\input\x808_cdls\\MI\\cdl_30m_r_mi_2008_albers'] ended with error
Process ended with non-zero return code 1. See errors in the (error) output.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `raster=` parameter of `g.region` needs to be a **GRASS raster**, not a tif file. You need to first import the tif into GRASS with `r.in.gdal`.

You can import the tif, and set the region to match the new raster in one go with the -e option to `r.in.gdal` like:

```
  r.in.gdal -e input="C:\Users\rit\Documents\PhD\Projects\Intensity\input\2008_cdls\MI\cdl_30m_r_mi_2008_albers.tif" output=cdl_30m_r_mi_2008_albers
```

Regarding your python script, have you done `import grass as gscript` ?

Comment: thanks @Micha, I do `import grass as gscript`, still getting an error (as noted in edit to my question above). Would appreciate if you could have a look

Comment: Two errors seem apparent: You did not add the "flags='e'" to your python call of run_command. And the output parameter needs to be a name for the GRASS raster, **not** a full path. Similar to my answer.